# Mod_rewrite best rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following URL: www.mydomain.com/messages.php?musician=musicianname. I want my url do display: www.mydomain.com/messages/musicianname.

What is the best mod_rewrite rule to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule messages/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /messages.php?musician=$1 [L]
```